# Are there any use cases for raise foo, bar in Python?

Tags: python, exception, python-2.x

Python 2 supports the following syntax for `raise`:

```
raise FooException(bar) # call
raise FooException, bar # positional
```

I thought that the positional syntax was just a historical result of old Python supporting arbitrary values as exceptions.

Are there any use cases for the positional syntax that can't be done (or are more verbose) with the call syntax?

Comment: "However, even Python 3 still supports it." Python 3.4 doesn't. It is a leftover from Python 2 days.

Comment: @DeepSpace huh, you're right. `raise Foo, bar` is illegal in py3k but `raise Foo()` is equivalent to `raise Foo`. I've updated the question.

Comment: I believe raise Foo is syntactic sugar for raise Foo() in Python 3.6 at least.

Comment: So are you asking about `raise FooException, bar` (which is no longer supported), or `raise FooException` ? You seem to have half-edited your question from the former to the latter, but I don't see how the latter qualifies as "positional syntax"

Comment: @khelwood fair point. I've removed the reference to `raise FooException` -- I agree the question was muddled before.

Comment: @WilfredHughes I'm afraid it is still a bit ambiguous. "Are there any use cases for the positional syntax that can't be done (or are more verbose) with the call syntax?" No, since the positional syntax is not supported any more.

Comment: @DeepSpace On Python 2, the positional syntax still exists, and I'm wondering if there's any use case for it. Is this clear?

Answer (score 0):

I'm addressing the edited version of the question in my answer, mainly

> However, even Python 3 considers raise Foo() and raise Foo to be equivalent.

The "call" syntax (`raise Foo(obj)`) will assign arbitrary object `obj` to the Exception object's `args` tuple attribute. While any object can be used as `obj`, this is mainly used for custom strings:

```
try:
    raise ValueError('a custom string')
except ValueError as e:
    print(e.args[0])
    # 'a custom string'
    print(e.args)
    # ('a custom string',)
```

This `args` tuple is actually used when printing the exception object, so it is pretty handy for logging:

```
 try:
     raise ValueError('custom error', 2)
except ValueError as e:
    print(e)
    # ('custom error', 2)
```

`raise ValueError()` assigns an empty tuple to `exc_obj.args`, so does `raise ValueError`.

This even works with multiple objects. In this case we will get a tuple of same length:

```
try:
    raise ValueError(1, 2, 3, 4)
except ValueError as e:
    print(e.args)
    # (1, 2, 3, 4)
```